# Importing Excel file into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, import-from-excel, truncation

I have an Excel file with these columns:

1. NatureAttitude
2. Intelligence
3. Career
4. Health
5. Other Skill

While importing that Excel file through import wizard I am getting the following error

> *Executing (Error) Messages Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with output column "Intelligence" (21) on output
>   "Excel Source Output" (9). The column status returned was: "Text was
>   truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code
>   page.". (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)*
>
> *Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "Intelligence" (21)" failed because truncation occurred, and the
>   truncation row disposition on "output column "Intelligence" (21)"
>   specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the
>   specified object of the specified component. (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)*
>
> *Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on component "Source MainSheetData$" (1) returned error code 0xC020902A. The component
>   returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
>   The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the
>   error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)*

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: change output column length for Intelligence to higher value.

Comment: I did it already by nvarchar(250) to nvarchar(max). But still the same error.

Comment: not in table, check in your Import Task wizard

Comment: solved through different method by converting in to Access and then importing it through import wizard i am able to import it. Thanks for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the same excel sheet into access. After that through import wizard i imported without any error. Thanks